# Can't use ES6 import syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use the ES6 import syntax and keep running into errors.
This is my data type,

```
class UnionFind{
    constructor(n){
        this.items = n;
    }

    union(p, q){

    }

    connected(p, q){

    }

    find(p){

    }

    count(){

    }

}
export default UnionFind
```

Saved in a file UnionFind.js

This the calling client,

```
import { UnionFind } from './unionFind';

const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input:process.stdin,
    output:process.stdout,
    terminal:false

});

uf = new UnionFind(10)

rl.on('numbers', function (line) {
    arr = number.split(' ')

    console.log(arr);
});
```

This is saved in a file client.mjs

This is how I'm running it,

```
node --experimental-modules union-find/client.mjs
```

I get the following error,

```
(node:13465) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///Users/mstewart/Dropbox/data-structures-algorithms-princeton/union-find/client.mjs:1
import { UnionFind } from './unionFind';
         ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'UnionFind'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/ModuleJob.js:89:21)
    at <anonymous>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: @nijm nope, you can see she's got the `experimental modules` flag set, which is documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html as not needing an extra library if set

Comment: @Derek  version 9.11.1

Comment: seems like you are trying to use named import on your default.

Comment: @Derek you are right

Answer (score 4):

In this case, use

```
       import UnionFind from './UnionFind.js';
```

if you declared

```
       export class UnionFind{ ....
```

then you use

```
import { UnionFind } from './UnionFind.js';
```

Also take a look at the file name:   UnionFind.js  . You are using './unionFind'. This is case sensitive

Comment: Tried both options, still keep getting the same error

Comment: Also take a look at the file name:   UnionFind.js  . You are using './unionFind'. This is case sensitive